# Ruby interpreter (CUI) 1.9.2p180 [i386-mingw32] has stopped working (I am not using MySQL)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, windows-7

My ruby interpreter is crashing on almost every page request with the following error:
Ruby interpreter (CUI) 1.9.2p180 [i386-mingw32] has stopped working

I am not using MySQL nor do I have the gem installed, as many of the posts online have suggested as a potential cause.  Where I can begin troubleshooting this issue?  My environment is stated as below.  This is a critical issue as I cannot continue development in this environment so any ideas would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks!

Windows 7 64bit
ruby 1.9.2p180 [i386-mingw32], installed with rubyinstaller
Rails 3.0.4
crashes with webrick/mongrel

Comment: What changed on your machine?

Comment: I found this topic searching in google and seems interesting: http://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/3840

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, i found the issue.  My css links somehow caused the windows ruby interpreter to crash if the media attribute isn't defined on more than 1 link (crazy!).

Original (crashes):

```
link rel="stylesheet" href="/stylesheets/jqModal.css" type="text/css"
link rel="stylesheet" href="/stylesheets/main.css" type="text/css"
```

Modified (doesn't crash):

```
link rel="stylesheet" href="/stylesheets/jqModal.css" type="text/css" media="screen, projection"
link rel="stylesheet" href="/stylesheets/main.css" type="text/css" media="screen, projection"
```

Here's some insight into the [same (or similar) issue](https://rails.lighthouseapp.com/projects/8994/tickets/5590-rails-30-crashes-ruby-192p0-on-repeated-browser-refresh).

Seems to be windows specific (again!) according to the post.

Comment: My link tag already has the media attribute set, but mine still crashes after a houple of hours being up. Rails 3, sqlite and mongrel.

Answer (score 4):

Workaround:

Add (or change)

config.log_level = :warn

in config/environments/development.rb

(not my solution - found it in another thread)

Comment: I tried the other suggestions first, and they eventually failed.  So far this config Change is working.  Are there any drawbacks to setting the log_level?

Comment: No; changing log level is standard procedure -- but obviously if you would ever want a different log_level, you're out of luck.

Answer (score 3):

It also happens when you want to link to missing files, before you actually create them.

Then the interpreter crashes after 2 requests in my case, but if you remove the missing file links 
it works just fine.

Comment: This fixed my issue, it was linking to a missing stylesheet.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem on windows, ruby interpreter crashing after every couple of pageloads.

my problem was here

```
<img src="<%= @game.image_url %>" />
```

and I fixed it with

```
<% if @game.image_url && @game.image_url != "" %>
 <img src="<%= @game.image_url %>" />
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1):

I had this error after precompiling files for heroku. After I deleted them from public/assets folder everything worked fine.