# Ruby interpreter (CUI) 1.9.2p180 [i386-mingw32] has stopped working - on the installation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, installation, devkit

I started to [install](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WUdDdiu8kBs) ruby, and the devkit according to this tutorial.

but i keep getting the same error when i try to open the cmd from ruby or to run a command on that folder:
Ruby interpreter (CUI) 1.9.2p180 [i386-mingw32] has stopped working

Comment: possible duplicate of [Ruby interpreter (CUI) 1.9.2p180 \[i386-mingw32\] has stopped working (I am not using MySQL)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5372888/ruby-interpreter-cui-1-9-2p180-i386-mingw32-has-stopped-working-i-am-not-us)

Answer (score 0):

Did you installed rvm.? May be there are some missing dependencies. There isn't much info in question, but you can do following:

1) if on ubuntu - update / install build-essential

2) Install RVM

3) type rvm requirements and look for dependencies under Ruby / Ruby Head and install them all.

4) rvm install 1.9.2-p180

Read this great article by Ryan Bigg: http://ryanbigg.com/2010/12/ubuntu-ruby-rvm-rails-and-you/

Comment: The question was for Ruby on Windows, which is neither Ubuntu nor has RVM.

Answer (score 0):

Download ANSICON v1.53. it's working fine for me in Window 8 X64 bit Env

Answer (score -1):

The problem was the ansicon i tried to installed to support the cucumber